# Need to sort varchar2 column

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a oracle table which contains two columns one is for the date (transaction date) and the other is for time (transaction time).  I am retrieving the data from a php file and displaying the data in HTML table. I am concatenating the two columns and display it as a single column in the report. My issue is that I need to sort that column and need to get the earliest one on top.

How can I do it. I tried to convert the date column to date through to_date but it didnt work.

Please help me in this

Comment: Please show queries that you have done so far. It would be much easier to help then.

Comment: Asking us to assist with an issue without giving details about your application (table structure, query, and so on) is like asking a mechanic to fix your car without letting him see the car. Please include all relevant information and details.

Comment: *'I tried to convert the date column to date through to_date but it didnt work.'*. Converting to a date is the correct solution, so the problem will be in how you tried to implement it. If you want us to help you need to post some sample data and the code you've already written. Also, please explain how it didn't work: hurled an exception? wouldn't compile? wrong order?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the table is not good. There are datatypes called `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` which can be easily sorted. If you store them as strings / `VARCHAR2', you need to write the sorting code yourself. I'd recommend to store it as a`TIMESTAMP` and convert your date and timestrings during insert:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (t TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO mytable (t) 
VALUES (to_timestamp('21.06.2818'||'08:12:27.35', 'DD.MM.YYYYHH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO mytable (t) 
VALUES (to_timestamp('21.06.2818'||'08:13:30.62', 'DD.MM.YYYYHH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

Ordering it is then trivial:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY t;
```

To convert the `TIMESTAMP` back to a string, just use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(t,'YYYY-MM-DD') as transaction_date,
       TO_CHAR(t,'HH24:MI:SS') as transaction_time
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY t;

TRANSACTION_DATE TRANSACTION_TIME
2818-06-21       08:12:27
2818-06-21       08:13:30
```

If you are an advance user, you could even stick the formatting code into two virtual columns:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (transaction_date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  TO_CHAR(t,'YYYY-MM-DD')));

ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (transaction_time GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  TO_CHAR(t,'HH24:MI:SS')));

SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY t;

TRANSACTION_DATE TRANSACTION_TIME
2818-06-21       08:12:27
2818-06-21       08:13:30
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to store the values using the `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type then:

- the values can be easily sorted chronologically.
- you can easily find dates within ranges.
- the database will store the values efficiently - using 7-bytes for a date and time together rather than requiring at least 8 characters for date and 6 for time when you store it as a string.

If you must (for business reasons) store the values as text then store them using ISO-8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD` and `HH24:MI:SS` (with leading zeroes) and then an alpha-numeric sort (which is the default for strings) will also sort them chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

I think sorting is a number.

Example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(t,'YYYY-MM-DD') as transaction_date,
   TO_CHAR(t,'HH24:MI:SS') as transaction_time
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```